# Regex to ignore all characters inbetween line item number and amount

Tags: regex

My row of text looks like this: 
1 SE20040021 B18204015560 24-04-2020 ABC LO 500319L 224.55
2 SE20040022 B10204006583 24-04-2020 KAR 170363Y 388.05

Where 1 or 2 at the beginning of string = line item number (line item number is pre-specified as either 1, 2, 3, etc)
where 224.55 or 388.05 = amount (always represented in positives with 2 decimal places)

I would like a Regex that after searching for the pre-specified line item number, it ignores unspecified amount of characters inbetween the line item number and amount.

Unspecified amount of characters in line item 1 or 2 are

> 1 SE20040021 B18204015560 24-04-2020 ABC LO 500319L
>   2 SE20040022 B10204006583 24-04-2020 KAR 170363Y

The returning result is:
For line item 1 return only string **224.55**
For line item 2 return only string **388.05**

Here's what I was using to return string for the numbers (^[0-9]+\d*.\d*$)
But I do not know how to match pattern with line item 1 and return string of the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get both values, you could use 2 capturing groups and match the space after the first group and the space before the last group.

```
^(\d+) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `.*`  Match a space, any char except a newline 0+ times and again a space
- `(\d+\.\d{2})` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits, a dot and 2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDdp1l/1)

Then you could use for example replacing using the 2 groups:

```
Line Item Number $1 = $2
```

**Update**

You could also use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^1 .* )\d+\.\d{2}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^1` Match 1 at the start of the string
  - `.*`  Match a space, any char except newline 0+ times and a space
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d+\.\d{2}` Match 1+ digits, a dot and 2 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9QRfM/1)

Comment: Oops. Ok I didn't get group 1 capture. But after that it seems to work. Here's what I am using for Line Item Number 1 ^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$)

Comment: I am trying this. It seems to work on the Regex demo. Am I getting this correct?
^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$
^(2) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$

Comment: Yes you can hardcode the value of the first group `^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$` See  https://regex101.com/r/ACPxqK/1

Comment: Line Item 1 Amount : Capture error - Unable to match a value using regex '\b(?<LineItem1Amt>^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$)\b'

Am getting this which is so strange

Comment: What is the tool or language?  Try it like this `^(?<LineItem1Amt>1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})$` https://regex101.com/r/vd3QTl/1

Comment: Got it!
^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})

I think it was because $ asserts the position at the end of the line. But my capture position is much larger

Comment: I now need to reformat the expression to only return the amount (\d+\.\d{2})$

Comment: Then you could use only a single capturing group `^1 .* (\d+\.\d{2})$`  https://regex101.com/r/ths3jT/1

Comment: Am using a program called ScantoPDF datagatherer plugin.

^1 .* (\d+\.\d{2}) for me returns the same results as ^(1) .* (\d+\.\d{2})

it returns the entire string from the first group to the last group

Comment: You are using it for searching only and getting the whole match. I don't know what the regex engine is, but you could try `\K` if it is supported. `^1 .* \K\d+\.\d{2}$`

Comment: Yes you are right. Am using it for searching. \K doesn't apply.

There is a reformatting expression after searching for the match. I can use {RemoveChars()} or {Replace()}

Comment: If you can use replace, then using this expression `^1 .* (\d+\.\d{2})$` will have the value in group 1. You can try using `\1` or `$1` in the replacement.

Comment: \1 or $1 is not working, let me check with the vendor

Comment: Did you find out if they support replacements with groups?

Comment: Did you find out if they support replacements with groups? Perhaps a positive lookbehind is supported `(?<=^1 .* )\d+\.\d{2}$` https://regex101.com/r/SA8xdG/1 or if Java `(?<=^1 .{0,1000} )\d+\.\d{2}$` https://regex101.com/r/sKAMO9/1 Perpaps you have to double escape the backslashes in the patterns like `(?<=^1 .{0,1000} )\\d+\\.\\d{2}$`

Comment: Cool! (?<=^1 .* )\d+\.\d{2} worked! I'll mark your answer as the solution! Oh I just found out I can't or am not sure how to. How do I mark this particular response as the answer? I would like to re-edit my question clearly to set out the requirements so that other users can see this for further support in future.

Comment: yes but how do I mark this latest chat as the answer? I would like to re-edit my question for clarity if you don't mind

Comment: @DerrickT I have updated the answer with the working pattern.

Comment: @DerrickT I see that you have updated your question, and removed the pattern that you tried. My advice would be to not remove that pattern or the question might get downvoted due to not showing what you have tried.

Comment: got it. Amended it to include the pattern previously which was not a  complete solution anyways because I only knew how to obtain the amount in digits to two decimal places.

Comment: I have adapted your answer to 
(?<=^1.*)\d*\,?\d*\.\d{2})\b

Reason being, I noticed on other sample data that the amount could include commas , due to amounts being greater than the hundred. 
1 I20030003C B18104010390 08-04-2020 ABC 794215K 7,452.10